# How to remove Ubuntu partition and boot menu?

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, uninstall

how do I completely remove the Ubuntu partition and the boot menu so I can just keep the Windows 7 partition and boot directly into it? I want to remove it all and so I can go and reside the partition also.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/25656)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hit from Google:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/

Please look for answers before posting a question, many have already been answered.